# $GL_2(\mathbb R)$ acting on $\hat{\mathbb R}=\mathbb R\cup \{\infty\}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

The question and its hint is given below:

[image]
[image]

But I could not understand what the question is trying to teach me, could anyone explain this for me please?

Also I could not understand how the hint could be used in the solution, could anyone explain this for me please?

Thank you!

Comment: The main point is $s(AB) x = s(A)(S(B) x)$. Why is it the case ? Because let $f(u,v) = \frac{u}{v}$ and $L_x = \{ (tx,t)^\top \in \mathbb{R}^2\}$ then $x = f(L_x)$ and $s(A) f(L_x) = f( AL_x)$.

Comment: You really ought to reflect on how poor your title was. Not only does it not describe the problem at all, it is a meaningless reference to some problem in some book *somewhere*.  I've suggested a better title for you this time, and in the future I'd like to encourage you to do something similar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But I could not understand what the question is trying to teach me

The problem is testing your understanding of the definition of a group acting on a set by having you work on a specific example: the group $GL_2(\mathbb R)$ acting on the set $\hat{\mathbb{R}}$.  If you can see what the connection is to the suggested transformation is and the group, then all you're doing is verifying group action axioms.

> Also I could not understand how the hint could be used in the solution

The hint is in case you fail to see the connection between the proposed action and $GL_2(\mathbb R)$.  (Yes, there are four numbers $a,b,c,d$ in the original proposition, but what do they have to do with matrices? Well, here's a hint...)

It explicitly outlines a correspondence between elements in $\hat{\mathbb R}$ and one dimensional subspaces of $\mathbb R^2$ plus the vertical line through $(0,0)$, and notes that the proposed action is simply matrix multiplication plus the extra rule that assigns meaning to the edge cases when $\infty$ appears for $x$ and $0$ appears in the denominator.

Comment: What about the case $ x= \infty$?

Comment: Hi @Intuition : You appear to be asking a question answered by the last line in my solution. If you disagree, then I need more help to understand what your question is. Regards

Comment: I am sorry for not remembering that this part was discussed in your answer .... because I read it long ago and I answered this question just by the action definition as you gave me a hint in your explanation